# How to create a model of face in opencv using java?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I am trying to convert this C++ code in this page  to java [(http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html)](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html)

I am stuck in the code

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(images, labels);
```

i am not able to find out the corresponding java functions for the above code.
With use of opencv how can i write this code??

Comment: that's a known bug, the native code for the java wrapper is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

There are sources, you can look at them and implement fisherfaces class by youself.

You can find the sources you need in file:

modules\contrib\src\facerec.cpp *(here is class Fisherfaces)*